# Error 413 when uploading large files using WCF Service on IIS7`

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wcf, iis-7

I have a web application which enables users to upload files. The files are then saved using a WCF service on another service. This uploading works fine until I upload a file around 4.5 MB. When I upload a file above a certain size, I get the error:

Soap Error: 413 The server is refusing to process a request because the request entity is larger than the server is willing or able to process...

This error appears in the system event log of the server on which the WCF service is running.

The solutions that I've found have told me to change the maxAllowedContentLength and uploadReadAheadSize settings in the applicationHost config file. However changing the maxAllowedContentLength to only created a different error if I set it to something really small and changing the uploadReadAheadSize value didn't have any effect on the problem. Does anyone know what I have to change and where I have to change it? I've been looking for hours and I'm starting to get impatient :(. Thanks for the help!

EDIT:

Ok the web.config of the WCF Service located in the  on the production system is as follows. This is the web.config located in the folder that the IIS Site of the WCF Web Services points to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        <add name="SOAP" path="*.wsdl" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\MSSoap\Binaries\SOAPIS30.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="bitness32" />
        <add name="WSDL Mapping" path="*.wsdl" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Program Files\Common Files\MSSoap\Binaries\SOAPIS30.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The configuration on the test system is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        <add name="WSDL Mapping" path="*.wsdl" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Program Files\Common Files\MSSoap\Binaries\SOAPIS30.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

As you can see, there is no mention of any content length or anything in either one of the files. I have to admit, I'm pretty stumped at this point. But like I said, I'm no expert in things IIS.

EDIT 2:

Here is the serviceModel node of my web application's web.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="WsJobsSoapBinding" closeTimeout="00:05:00" openTimeout="00:05:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
                <security mode="None">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://srvts01test:90/WsJobs.WSDL" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WsJobsSoapBinding" contract="JobsWs.WsJobsSoapPort" name="WsJobsSoapPort"/>
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

This is the web.config of my web application that calls the WCF service and not the web.config of the WCF service itself. Thanks again for any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an article that talks about the 45KB size limit you mentioned in the chat.  It includes the configuration changes that were made.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/166763/WCF-Streaming-Upload-Download-Files-Over-HTTP

It's possible that your test environment has these changes made so that's one thing to look for/consider.  People sometimes don't overwrite configuration files during deployment so you may have an old file there that just works.

Comment: Thank you, Shane! I'll check it out!

Comment: I ended up writing a new WCF service myself. The problem seemed to be with SOAP. It's working fine with the new WCF service now :). Thanks again for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

You want to change the MaxReceivedMessageSize.

I think when I did this I also had to change the MaxBufferPoolSize to the same value.

You can do it via the config or via code like this.

```
            binding.MaxBufferPoolSize = 67108864;
            binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 67108864;
```

Comment: Where exactly is this property? In the applicationHost config? Thanks for the feedback :)

Comment: Could you give me the context in which this appears? Is it inside the standardEndpoint node of a config file? If so, in which config file? I apologize for my noobness but I'm pretty new to IIS.

Comment: I found the properties but only in the web.config of my web application. The web application uses WCF services located on another server to save the files and when it tries to save the files using the WCF services, the 413 error occurs on the machine that hosts the WCF services. I forgot to mention that we have a version running on a test system with all the same configurations (of the web application at least) and it works there. It's just not working on the production server for some reason... So I don't think changing anything in the web.config of the web app will fix the problem.

Comment: That would have been good information to share ;(  I'll have to think about this some more.  It would be in the endpoint config on the WCF service itself.  Can you show that config in the main question?  Are you self hosting the WCF service, or using IIS?

Comment: What behaviour happens on the web site when the WCF server throws the 413?  Are you catching any errors on that side?

Comment: I noticed now that a file with a size of 41.5KB uploads successfully whereas a file with a size of 83.1KB fails to upload. I read that the default value for the uploadReadAheadSize is around 48KB but changing the uploadReadAheadSize value still never changed the behavior.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your responses till just now. The behavior that happens on the web site when the error is thrown is that my web app logs and throws an exception because the response from the server hosting the WCF service is returning an error page (Server 500 error etc). Since my web app tries to interpret the WCF responses as XML strings, it throws an exception and the user is rerouted to an error page. I'll try and post the config in the main question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8791/discussion-between-ctrldot-and-chris-braunschweiler)

Comment: There is no stacktrace on the WCF side. I didn't write the WCF code. All I know is that the WCF method that's being called by the web application never actually gets called. The only thing that happens is that a server error message is returned to the web application. In the event viewer of the machine running the WCF services, the event viewer shows an MSSOAP error with the message in the question (Soap Error: 413 The server is refusing...). The WCF services are hosted on an IIS server on a machine separate from the machine that hosts the IIS with the web application.

Answer (score 0):

I was also having these 413 errors in my WCF Service, which was running under .Net 4.5.

The solution was simple.

Previously, my web.config contained this:

```
  <services>
    <service name="PocketCRMServices.Service1">
      <endpoint address="../Service1.svc"
        binding="webHttpBinding"
        contract="PocketCRMServices.IService1"
        behaviorConfiguration="webBehaviour" />
    </service>
  </services>
```

So, by default, it was already using the `webHttpBinding` binding.

To get rid of the 413 errors, I just needed to add this straight after this section:

```
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
             maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647777" >
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                    maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                    maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

And that's it.